# Laravel 5.1 DB::table chunk for a Restful API and Angular.JS

Tags: mysql, angularjs, laravel-5.1, angularjs-1.5

Is there a way to chunk millions of records in a Restful API call?

I am using Angular.JS / Ionic for the client and have a restful API that works great with smaller number of records about 10,000.  But my database has a couple of million records and if I make an api call to show all records it returns http Response Code 500.  The reason I want to pull all the data is so that users can search the matching product using ng-model="query".  On the client only 100 handpicked records will be displayed.  I looked at the Laravel documentation  and it suggests chunking the data.  I tried the following code but I get the 500 http response code error.  I am using mysql as the database.  Eventually Iw ill be building a redis cache but to begin with I need to b able to fetch all the results.

$productlist = DB::table('productlist')->chunk(1000, $products) {
        foreach ($products as $product) {

```
    $productlist = array_merge($products, $product);
    }
    });     

 return $productlist;
```

Comment: Why don't you use pagination? And it's a good practice to send your query to the server and get filtered results instead of getting all the results and then doing filter on client side.

Comment: @Amit - think about pagination user experience on a mobile device when user intent is search.   Most of the mobile apps I have worked with doesn't user pagination.  They perform an autocomplete while search.  The challenge is that API has make all the results available  to search through.

Comment: I could be wrong but I wouldn't imagine that other apps pull through all 10,000 rows (or whatever the number is) in one go. Chances are they send through a subset and then implement some sort of lazy loading in scroll (which pagination would be fine for). Also, chunking that data and sending through wont give the result you're hoping for. Again, this would be a good use case for pagination (just used in a slightly different way).